# Use of IN clause in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

I need to fetch data from database by executing something along the lines of:

```
query2 = """ select Comment, CONVERT(RUNID, CHAR(20)) AS RUNID from abc where Comment like '{}' and RUNID IN %s """.format(form['error_message'], id_list)
            cursor = connections['xyz'].cursor()
            cursor.execute(query2)
```

Here form['error_message'] is a string, and id_list is a list of strings. The query that i have constructed in resulting in an error. Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: add parentheses: `runid in (3,7,2)`

Comment: Hi juergen.. I tried something along the lines of  RUNID IN (%s). It still didn't work.

Comment: You are going to need some single quotes in there?  the statement will need to resolve to something like this: `RUNID IN ('value1', 'value2')`.  Also, if you get an error message then it's incredibly useful to post it into your question.

Comment: Actually it is a django app, so all I'm getting on the output is a custom json message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
quoted_ids = list(map(lambda x:"'{}'".format(x),id_list))
query2 = """select Comment, CONVERT(RUNID, CHAR(20)) AS RUNID from abc where Comment like '{0}' and RUNID IN ({1}) """.format(form["error_message"],",".join(quoted_ids))
cursor = connections['xyz'].cursor()
cursor.execute(query2)
```

Comment: Hi Gabip. Thanks for looking into this. This is showing me a syntax error on the first line of your stated code.

Comment: which python version do you use? this works for python3

Comment: Yeah I'm on python 3 too!

Comment: Could you add your stacktrace please? this code works for me well

Comment: Umm I'm not sure if this is what you asked for, but I looked into the logs and I'm getting _OSError: write error_

Comment: Stack trace is the full exception message. But wait, my snippet code not supposed to return OSError. Are you sure that you run only this code?

Comment: Actually this code snippet is a part of a django app. The syntax error I'm getting is shown on the browser: SyntaxError at /hello/search/

invalid syntax (views.py, line 90)

Comment: Please share as much information as you can. Sharing view.py will be very helpful in this case. 
Could you try to run the code I shared in the python console to eliminate other possible issues?

Comment: I would have definitely shared it, but it is a huge piece of code. Also, if I comment out your code, The error goes away. Also you are right, the OSError is not because of your code, but some other app.

Comment: Did you try to run my code in python console? does it throw the same error?

Comment: Yup. Tried it on an ide, same error of invalid syntax.

Comment: Edited my solution, please try it :)

Comment: I tried it out, the syntax error is gone but my issue isn't. I tried printing quoted_ids, it gives an out put of _["'{x}'", "'{x}'"]_ . Is this correct?

Comment: No, `quoted_ids` should include the actual values but quoted, not x.